# WordPress URL loading for Multiple Languages

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website which has two languages English and Arabic, and I want to achieve the following scenario:

the links look like this : www.example.com/wp/ar for Arabic -  www.example.com/wp/ for English.

I want to make it accessible like this :
www.example.com/ar
www.example.com/en

Without creating new WordPress for each languages.

Please note that I have another application in the WEBROOT which I don't want to be affected. www.example.com

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of those two plugins to manage translation easily :
https://wpml.org/ | https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

They basically do the same job, and both quite famous. I mostly use qTranslate, so I can confirm it does what you need.